# Browser capabilities in spec description in Protractor Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, protractor, httpbrowsercapabilities

I want to generate two separate report for a single test case. For that, I am using `browser.getCapabitities` method in the test by which I am getting the browser name and version.

Now, when I use this variable at the end of the spec description, the value is `undefined`. The `browserNameforSpec` is getting value before describe. Only when I use this value at the end of the spec, it shows undefined. I am not able to get the reason why this happens. Is there any way to change the name of this spec description before test started.

My code is

```
let capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
let browserNameforSpec;
capsPromise.then(function(caps) {
    console.log(caps);
    let browserName = caps.get('browserName');
    let browserVersion = caps.get('version');
    browserNameforSpec = browserName + '-' + browserVersion + '-';
    console.log(browserNameforSpec);

});

describe( '0030 Test for login' + browserNameforSpec, function () { // this.browserNameforSpec value is undefined

    // 1.
    it('Navigate to the login page', async () => {
        await navigate.to.the(loginPage);
    });

    // 2
    it('Click onto language button', async() => {
        await click.onto(languageButton);
        await expect(languageDropdown.isDisplayed());
    });

    // 3
    it('English Language is selected', async() => {    
        await click.onto(englishLanguage);
        await expect(languageButton.getText()).toBe('English');
    });

    // 4.
    it('Correct user name is written into email field', async() => {
        await usernameField.click();
        await enter(correctUsername, into(usernameField));    
    });

    // 5.
    it('Correct password is written into password field', async() => {
            await passwordField.click().then(function () {
                passwordField.clear();
                enter(correctPassword, into(passwordField));
            })    
    });

    // 6.
    it('Login button is clicked and home page is opened', async() => {
        await click.onto(loginButton);
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is : 
**1.** You are using this.browserNameforSpec which will be undefined as the function context gets changed, You have declared browserNameforSpec as a variable which is directly available in all function but you are calling on this)
**2.** browser.getCapabilities() returning an instance of Promise that's why the execution flow is different. First it is executing this function and the describe(). But. they need to be called in sync manner.

Below code is using another .then for executing it in a sequential manner. Try to use below code :

```js
let capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
let browserNameforSpec;

capsPromise
    .then(function(caps) {
        console.log(caps);
        let browserName = caps.get('browserName');
        let browserVersion = caps.get('version');
        browserNameforSpec = browserName + '-' + browserVersion + '-';
        console.log(browserNameforSpec);

    })
    .then(function() {
        describe( '0030 Test for login' + browserNameforSpec, function () {

            // 1.
            it('Navigate to the login page', async () => {
                await navigate.to.the(loginPage);
            });

            // 2
            it('Click onto language button', async() => {
                await click.onto(languageButton);
                await expect(languageDropdown.isDisplayed());
            });

            // 3
            it('English Language is selected', async() => {

                await click.onto(englishLanguage);
                await expect(languageButton.getText()).toBe('English');
            });

            // 4.
            it('Correct user name is written into email field', async() => {
                await usernameField.click();
                await enter(correctUsername, into(usernameField));

            });

            // 5.
            it('Correct password is written into password field', async() => {
                    await passwordField.click().then(function () {
                        passwordField.clear();
                        enter(correctPassword, into(passwordField));
                    })

            });

            // 6.
            it('Login button is clicked and home page is opened', async() => {
                await click.onto(loginButton);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: The value is still undefined. here is the result 1. 0030 Test for correct login undefined[chrome #01]

Comment: I think in this test will not run. because I am getting  No specs defined!problem trying to remove a folder. and no spec is running

Comment: Not sure, what you are taking about?

Comment: The test does not run. Error is No specs defined. I tried this way before. but this did not work

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code in your `onPrepare()`

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
  browser.browserName = cap.caps_.browserName;
});
```

You call in your test as below

```
describe( '0030 Test for login' + browser.browserName, function () {

    // 1.
    it('Navigate to the login page', async () => {
        await navigate.to.the(loginPage);
    });
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: I am getting this error for the first line TypeError: Cannot read property 'browserName' of undefined